# How to hide tab bar in chrome but still use tabs?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, google-chrome-extensions, tabs

I use the **Tabs Outliner** plugin in Google Chrome because I like to see my tabs organized hierarchically.  The issue I have is that tabs still display in their normal place (horizontally across the top) *as well as* in the Tabs Outliner window.  This wastes space by duplicating data.

#### Options I've considered

1. Full screen mode isn't what I need because I still need access the the URL bar.  Full screen hides the URL bar, the extension buttons and other elements that I like.
2. Someone suggested using `javascript:window.open(location.href, "detab", "toolbar=0"); window.close();` to create a new window.  This looks promising, but, alas, opening a new tab in this "minimalist" window puts that new tab back on a window with tabs (not at all what I'm looking for).
3. Using another browser is a possibility.  I've used Firefox with the "Tree Style Tab" plugin.  But sometimes only Chrome is available.
4. Moving the window slightly off the screen is a possibility, but this is a pretty terrible solution.
5. Any sort of "boss key" options seem to be out.  These don't hide your tabs and let you keep browsing.  They give you a new empty window that shows the tab bar.  Not a solution.

Nothing that makes the tab bar invisible temporarily will do.  If opening a new window or a new tab will make it reappear, that completely defeats the purpose.  I want one set of tabs visible and one set only: the Tabs Outliner tabs.

I find horizontal tabs to be pretty obnoxious.  Screens have far less vertical space than horizontal, so why use up vertical space with a horizontal bar?  The horizontal bar also has no hierarchy, so you can't tell, for example, which page of Google search results opened a given tab.

Comment: Came across your question and wondered the same. I wonder if it's possible to create a custom browser theme and use some css trickery to hide the tabs?

Edit: Seems CSS is not possible... https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/themes#manifest